# Why is Ansible task getting stuck for so long?

Tags: ansible, ubuntu

I'm new to Ansible, I've made a playbook with only two tasks as shown below:

```
- name: Installing Kubernetes for the master node
  connection: ssh
  hosts: x.x.x.x
  become_method: su

  tasks:

    - name: installing curl 
      ansible.builtin.shell: 
        cmd: sudo apt install --yes apt-transport-https curl
      vars: 
        ansible_persistent_log_messages: True    
      register: update_curl_install_output

    - name: update output
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: update_curl_install_output.stdout_lines
```

My ansible.cfg:

```
[ssh_connection]

ssh_args = -o ServerAliveInterval=100 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=2m
enable_task_debugger = True
```

And running the playbook with the following command:

```
ANSIBLE_ENABLE_TASK_DEBUGGER=True ansible-playbook -vvv master-node.yaml -i inventory --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=managed_host_pass"
```

The remote host is easily getting connected, but the task is getting stuck for a long while. The logs below show nothing atypicality.

```
<192.168.1.15> (0, b'', b'')                                                                                                                                                
<192.168.1.15> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: adil                                                                                                                      
<192.168.1.15> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d11 ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=100 -o ControlPersist=2m -o 
'User="adil"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/7bf699d458 -tt 
 192.168.1.15 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /home/adil/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp- 
 1679218469.1440735-1171472-85023283189053/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
```

And after that it shows no logs, completely stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Answering those who could face the same problem. I solved the problem, it was due to putting the escalation method in the playbook.

```
become_method: su
```

Rather than it should be this

```
become: true
```